# How to select brown pixels on .tiff image and compute the area or a number of them in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, mahotas

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import pylab
import pymorph
import mahotas
from scipy import ndimage

image = mahotas.imread('img.tiff')

pylab.imshow(image)
pylab.show()
```

I want to select (threshold) brown pixels (vessels) on medical image and compute the area which they do represent.  How can I do that in Python like in Matlab or C++? Are there any good examples I could not find?

Thank you

Comment: What is your rule for "brown"? There's no brown color plane that you can threshold on; you need to describe it in terms of RGB (or CMYK or some other reasonable colorspace). If you can write the rule just in terms of a function `is_brown(r, g, b)`, or even write the rule in Matlab or C++ terms, the question should be answerable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your rule for "brown" is, but presumably it's something like this (in the RGB colorspace):

```
0.5 <= r < 0.75 and 0.25 <= g < 0.375 and b < 0.1
```

An `ndimage` is just a 3D array of pixels, where the third dimension is the color plane. In other words, for an RGBA image, `image[0, 0, 0]` is the red value for pixel `(0, 0)`, `image[0, 0, 1]` is the green value for pixel `(0, 0)`, etc.

So, you'd got an array of pixels. You want to count all pixels that match that rule. You don't need any image-specific functions for that. Just use your favorite `numpy` mechanism for applying a function to all of the planes at each row and column to get yourself a 2x2 array of bools. For example:

```
browns = ((image[:,:,0] >= 0.50) & (image[:,:,0] < 0.75) &
          (image[:,:,1] >= 0.25) & (image[:,:,1] < 0.375) &
          (image[:,:,2] < 0.1))
```